# Simple JavaScript code crashed Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, crash, firebug

In Firebug's console

```
var a = [];
a[0] = a;
```

crashed Firefox!

Why?

**edit:**

1. This statement is logically correct, and there is nothing bad about referencing recursion. Therefor it's a bug in <strike>browser</strike> Firebug.
2. Works fine in Chrome and Opera.
3. I'm using last official versions of Firebug and Firefox

**edit 2:** It crashes in Firebug console and works in native Firefox web console

Comment: Very interesting, to push the array into itself. I think this is an infinite recursion, that's why it crashes FF, and would probably crash any browser. In what purpose your'e intend to use this kind of an array?

Comment: @GGG Hmm, when assigning the first array into the first index (or any index) of the same array, assigning continues forever. Isn't that a crash?

Comment: @Teemu nope, try it in the console... it creates an object with a property referring to itself, but this is not uncommon (`window.self`, `window.top`, etc.).

Comment: @GGG Yep, I tested it. There was interesting results, no crash even in inspecting, not even in FF. If it is worthwhile, try this: var `a=new Array(); a[0]=a; a[0][0]='foo'; alert(a[0][0]);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a firebug bug.

It works fine in the built-in firefox console (ctrl+shift+k), the chrome console, and the opera console.

I'd file a bug report with firebug.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing inherently wrong doing that, however you are building a data structure that "contains" itself (actually contains a reference to itself).

When displaying this kind of structure if the code has not been written thinking to this possibility it's likely that the debugger will recurse forever (up to SO :-) ), trying to get to the end of the infinite chain

```
a[0][0][0][0]...
```

Comment: Interestingly it works just fine in Chrome, which seems to only inspect properties of an object once you expand it. Now I wonder how `top.top.top...` doesn't break firebug.

Comment: Come on! it do NOT creates a[0][0].... ! This reference is valid but there is no separate object for it, it is referencing to same __a__

Comment: @Viller: no one said that. The problem is just if the algorithm that Firebug uses to convert to a string representation is able to handle self-referencing arrays.